# Update column/Join in QGIS similar Mapinfo

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, spatial-join

Looking somewhat similar to UPDATE COLUM option ( for join) MapInfo in QGIS. This exists ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Update data on joined tables?

Comment: Hi, how are you. What I try to do is then updated columns in a data layer with another layer. For example , I have two layers A = Poligono , B = Points . The layer B contains enterros values. Entonce would do two things. 1. Count how many points of the layers B are within the layer A. 2. From the points of the layer B that are within the polygon layer A, I need the sum of their values ​​and paste this sum in a column of created layer A.

I hope I have been able to explain .

greetings and thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The refFunctions plugin does what you want by allowing you to update the values of a field in one layer with those from another layer. Once installed, you'll see a new option in the field calculator called *Reference*. In your case you want to use the *geomwithin* function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I'll try and share if it was what he wanted. Thank you

Comment: If you make this a virtual attribute, it will automatically update.